# How to add a second app to Phusion Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have my Phusion Passenger Nginx configured to as below :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  blog.abc.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /app/public;
}
```

Im about to host the main site `abc.com` also in this machine. How can I do that (Its a separate app)? Is it possible to add another server block like this :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  abc.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /app2/public;
}
```

Comment: just append the second in your nginx.conf as include or append in the config you did the first host definition.

Comment: do you wanted to run second app on sub-URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phusion Passenger author here. Yes. Just add another virtual host block for the other app. It works exactly as expected.

Comment: Worked like a charm :) What is the advantage we get when adding it to the same server block? Two server blocks take too much resources?

Comment: There are no advantages. The server blocks only dictate HTTP-to-application routing, i.e. which HTTP host names and URLs the web server should map to which application. Resource usage is exactly the same no matter how the routing is configured.

Answer (score 1):

I configured my second app on sub-uri of first app. Below is the nginx conf and settings what i done.

nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;
  location / {
    root   /var/www/demo/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
  }

  location /test {
    root   /var/www/demo;
    passenger_base_uri /test;
    passenger_enabled on;
 }
```

Then add symbolic link:

```
ln -s /var/www/logger/public /var/www/demo/test
```

Comment: What is the advantage we get when adding it to the same server block? Two server blocks take too much resources?